# radio button form immediate price calculation

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have written a javascript code for a form to calculate price while user types a number in the textbox. The calculation formula changes based on the number that users type in the textbox.

For example, if the number is between 0 and 1200 the Total price = (200000 + 166.7 x facadeArea )x(projectStyle)x(projectFunction).

The problem is that the total price doesn't change at all. 
please help me.

```
<html>
<font face = "Algerian" ><h2>What Kind of Project Would You Like to Order?
</h2></font>
<form name ="mdl">



Project style:<br/>
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">modern
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.8" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">classic
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.6" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">traditional
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.7" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">prarmetric
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.3" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">organic
<input type="hidden" name="options">
<br/>


Project function:<br/>
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">villa
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.4" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">apartment
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.5" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">commercial
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.6" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">official
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.3" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">other
<input type="hidden" name="style">
<br/>

Facade Area <br/>
&nbsp &nbsp <input type="text" name="area" value="0" 
onchange="estimateTotal(this);">sqm 
<input type="hidden" name="area">
<br/>


<p>Total Price: <input type="text" name="total_price" value="0" 
readonly="readonly"></p>

</form>
</html>


code:

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var projectStyle = 
        document.querySelector('input[name=options]:checked').value,
        projectFunction = 
        document.querySelector('input[name=style]:checked').value,
        facadeArea = document.getElementByName('area').value;


       function estimateTotal(input) {
 var total = parseFloat(mdl.total_price.value);
 var value = parseFloat(input.value);

    if (input.type === 'radio') {
    if (input.name === 'options') {
       if (facadeArea == 0) {total = 0;}
       else if (facadeArea > 0 && facadeArea <= 1200) {
               total = parseInt(200000 + 166.7 * 
 facadeArea)*projectStyle*projectFunction;} 
       else if (facadeArea > 1200 && facadeArea <= 4000) {
               total = parseInt(400000 + 35.71 * 
 facadeArea)*projectStyle*projectFunction;} 
       else if (facadeArea > 4000 && facadeArea <= 10000) {
               total = parseInt(500000 + 16.66 * 
facadeArea)*projectStyle*projectFunction;}
       else {total = 700000;}
    }

  }


    mdl.total_price.value = total;
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are encountering? Is the total not displayed at all **OR** Are you getting an incorrect total sum **OR** Is it a system error?

Comment: What is it that doesnt work? Do you get an error? Is the calculated price wrong? Doesnt anything happen?

Comment: The error is that the total price is wrong. just shows "700000"

Comment: Please update the question and add that information. Also tell us what input gave that result and what result you are expecting. the best would be if you could create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few different issues:

Your query selectors would through errors if one group of named inputs or the others weren't selected.

The `document.getElementsByName` function returns a HTMLCollection which doesn't have a `.value` property. This was fixed by referencing the element using `document.getElementsByName('area')[0].value`

Because that value wasn't being set the result of your `if` statement always resulted in `total = 700000;`

That value also needed so converted to a number using `Number` for your `if` statements to work correctly.

```js
        var ps = 'input[name="options"]:checked';
        var pf = 'input[name="style"]:checked'

        function estimateTotal(input) {
            if (!document.querySelector(ps) || document.querySelector(ps).length == 0) return;
            if (!document.querySelector(pf) || document.querySelector(pf) .length == 0) return;

            var projectStyle = document.querySelector(pf).value;
            var projectFunction = document.querySelector(ps).value;
            facadeArea = Number(document.getElementsByName('area')[0].value);

            var total = parseFloat(mdl.total_price.value);
            var value = parseFloat(input.value);

            if (input.type === 'radio') {
            if (input.name === 'options') {
            if (facadeArea == 0) {
                total = 0;
            } else if (facadeArea > 0 && facadeArea <= 1200) {
                total = parseInt(200000 + 166.7 *
                    facadeArea) * projectStyle * projectFunction;
            } else if (facadeArea > 1200 && facadeArea <= 4000) {
                total = parseInt(400000 + 35.71 *
                    facadeArea) * projectStyle * projectFunction;
            } else if (facadeArea > 4000 && facadeArea <= 10000) {
                total = parseInt(500000 + 16.66 *
                    facadeArea) * projectStyle * projectFunction;
            } else {
                total = 700000;
            }
             }

            }


            mdl.total_price.value = total;
        }
```

```html
  <font face="Algerian">
        <h2>
            What Kind of Project Would You Like to Order?
        </h2>
    </font>
    <form name="mdl">


        <div>
            Project style:
        </div>
        <div>
            &nbsp &nbsp
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">modern &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.8" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">classic &nbsp &nbsp
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.6" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">traditional &nbsp &nbsp
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.7" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">prarmetric &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="options" value="1.3" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">organic
            <input type="hidden" name="options">
        </div>
        <div> Project function</div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="style" value="1" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">villa &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.4" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">apartment &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.5" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">commercial
            &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.6" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">official &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="style" value="1.3" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">other
            <input type="hidden" name="style">
            <br /> Facade Area <br /> &nbsp &nbsp <input type="text" name="area" value="0" onchange="estimateTotal(this);">sqm
            <input type="hidden" name="area">
        </div>
        <br />


        <p>Total Price: <input type="text" name="total_price" value="0" readonly="readonly"></p>

    </form>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The code works now. Another problem is that, I want to have the code in a separate javascript file but seems the code doesn't work. Should I change some parts of the code while I want to use it in a separate file? I receive this error: "input is not define"

Comment: That way I have the code setup now it shouldn't matter where you put it. `input is not defined` means you have something calling `estimatetotal` with out passing `this` as a paramater. Make sure all your elements are `onchange="estimateTotal(this);"`

Comment: Yes. I forgot to define onchange="estimateTotal(this);" for some elements. Thanx